# How do I gather user input in a loop, and then use a loop to access that input?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, loops, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm attempting to take user input using a `for` loop and bash's `read` utility. (*Using bash version 5.0.17*) As there are multiple inputs, I am using the `i` iterator to differentiate each input that is entered.  That part works as I can `echo` the variable.

What I have not figured out, is how to access those variables, dynamically, in another loop.  What I had in mind was to use the `num` variable again in the second loop because I need to loop the same amount of times to bring the data in and output the data later.  I was thinking that I can just use the `i` iterator again, as an index, that would concatenate to the string and I would be able to access the variable.  However that is not so.

What I've tried:

- If I use `echo "$str$i"` that will not work because the variable "str" does not exist.  Therefore the out put was just `0` and `1`
- I tried using a string **str** and tried to concat it with the variable `$i`; `echo "str$i"` but that just gave me the output `str0` and `str1`
- I also had a few string literal attempts but that was messy.

Lines 10 and 11 `echo $str0` and `echo $str1` show me that those variable are created and accessible because I get the output `qwe` and `asd`.  So how would I loop through to access each of those variables so that the output of the second loop is also `qwe` and `asd`?

Please see the code below and the resulting output below that:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "How many variables to loop?: " num

for (( i=0; i<num; i++ ))
do
  read -p "Enter no. $[i+1] string: " str$i
done
# assuming you enter at least two
echo $str0
echo $str1

echo ++++++++++++++++++++ 
# I would like to loop through however many entries were entered above
# but I cannot figure out how to do this.
for (( i=0; i<num; i++ ))
do
  echo "$str$i"
#   echo "str$i"
done
```

```
$ ./concat.sh
How many variables to loop?: 2
Enter no. 1 string: qwe
Enter no. 2 string: asd
qwe
asd
++++++++++++++++++++
0
1
```

I did look into an array solution but my brain is fried from working on the above.  If an array is the way to go, lemme know!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may consider using an array and `readarray` builtin (a synonym for `mapfile`) with `-n` option.

Comment: Hello there, thanks so much for the suggestion.  I found my answer here using an array:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/29215/how-can-i-read-user-input-as-an-array-in-bash
Thanks again!

Comment: The accepted answer in the link you gave is debatable and likely inefficient. It assumes each array element will contain a single word (that is, won't contain a blank character).

Comment: The answer I used was the one with 4 upvotes.  I implemented it with a for loop.  I really just needed the syntax on how to put user input into an array.  This is for a very small and simple script so performance is not a big deal.